# Google Blobstore App Engine tutorial

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, jsp, blobstore

Update see below

I'm trying to build this blobstore app engine sample from this google tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Uploading_a_Blob

This is what I have. I can select a file to upload.

http://instantedituploader.appspot.com/

When I hit submit I get this error:

```
    Error: Not Found

    The requested URL /%3C%=%20blobstoreService.createUploadUrl(?foo=&myFile=sprayerpic.jpg was not found on this server.
```

I'm fairly certain I'm missing:

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>

<%
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
%>
```

I took it out because I couldn't figure out how to include that in the index.html. The tutorial uses a jsp file to include the above and the html for the upload form/submit. How do I do this?

UPDATE----------------------

Ok I switched the index.jsp to my welcome file. Now I get a 500 Server Error this is what shows up in the app engine console and I also get a /favicon.ico error too.

```
013-09-18 08:33:08.601 / 500 3477ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.10 Chromium/22.0.1229.94 Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
W 2013-09-18 08:33:08.412 EXCEPTION java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Serve at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-cb1588546d641fbb(Request.java) at java.lang.Class
E 2013-09-18 08:33:08.414 javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Serve at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
W 2013-09-18 08:33:08.419 EXCEPTION java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Upload at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-cb1588546d641fbb(Request.java) at java.lang.Clas
E 2013-09-18 08:33:08.420 javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Upload at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
W 2013-09-18 08:33:08.591 Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@d206ca{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~instantedituploader/1.370311
C 2013-09-18 08:33:08.597 Uncaught exception from servlet javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed. at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMa
I 2013-09-18 08:33:08.600 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in the example are Java Server Pages. See the docs on how to [use JSPs with GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps).

You should rename `index.html` to `index.jsp` and set it as a welcome file in your `web.xml` (welcome page is served when user invokes the root `/`):

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>path/to/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: From a standard perspective where is the index.jsp supposed to go? Within the war directory or the web-inf?

Comment: Anywhere in WEB-INF - if you put it into subdir than you must use the whole path from root of WEB-INF when referring it. War is generated and files are overwritten on build (if changed).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I placed the index.jsp in the web-inf and set the welcome file to index.jsp and got rid of the index.html. Now if you click that link above I get a 500 Server Error, I've posted the stack above from app engine console.